# MySQL Insert statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
   INSERT INTO 'subactivity' VALUES (NULL, '2013-02-05', 'On Deck', '100.100.100', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Display On Deck list', NULL, NULL)
```

The above command returns a message saying I have a syntax error when run through PHPmyAdmin or in a browser out of Dreamweaver. There are 10 values and 10 fields. It fails even when I list the field names. The fields with NULL content, allow NULL in the structure with a default value of NULL. The content of the values matches the field type.

The first field is a key, auto-increment field. The second and fifth fields are date fields. All other fields are text.

I'm at a loss to figure out what I'm doing wrong and I'm hoping someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the ' surrounding the table name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Error in PHP MySQL "Insert" query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551284/getting-error-in-php-mysql-insert-query)

Answer (score 4):

The table name should have backticks `` ` `` around it, NOT single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   INSERT INTO `subactivity` VALUES (NULL, '2013-02-05', 'On Deck', '100.100.100', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Display On Deck list', NULL, NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just get rid of the single quotes?  And add a ; at the end of your statement.